# injected dll can't freeze when OpenFileDialog->ShowDialog();

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I created a project dll, that contains `form1` and the `mainDll.cpp`, when i inject the Dll in my target process, all is okay, all functions, and the `form1` is called in the `mainDLL.cpp`, then the `form1` is opended in the same memory space of the target process, but today i was trying to put a `OpenFileDialog` in a button of this form.

```
button Code
{
    OpenFileDialog1->ShowDialog();
}
```

The problems is when i click on the button , then the Form loaded by the Dll freeze, not the target process, only the Process that i injectet it's `FORM1`;

Comment: What do you mean by "freezing"? Do you do something to freeze the process/thread?

Comment: Frezzing, lock, the form load by the dll injection in the process/thread, its i made the same procedures in a common process to OpenFileDialog1->ShowDialog(), and its works wells, but in this form create from the dll injected in the other thread, when i click on the button thats Shows the Dialog, the form stay freezed. it do nothing not answer mouse clicks, keyboards, nothing.